# Removing what is likely an unnecessary line of code

Tags: python, dataframe

I am currently adding a 3rd column to a dataFrame:

```
per_day           =    dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].count().reset_index(name='Trx')
per_day_burned    =    dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].sum().reset_index(name='Burned') 
per_day['Burned'] = per_day_burned['Burned']
```

Here I am adding per_day['Burned'] to per_day.

Is there a way to do it without having the second line of code and just add it directly to the per_day dataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple aggregations on the same group with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html).

```
dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].agg(['count', 'sum'])
```

Comment: this makes the column called count and sum. how can i change these names?

Comment: `.rename(columns=...)`

Comment: this does not work: per_day                   = dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'].agg(['count', 'sum']).rename(columns='a','b')

Comment: also how would i agg a third thing? this does not work: per_day                   = dg.groupby(dg['DateTime'].dt.date)['Burned'],['percent_burned'].agg(['count', 'sum','max'])

Comment: `[['burned', 'percent_burned']]`

Comment: but your answer performs both count and sum on Burned. How do i distinguish which class to perform each operation on?

Comment: See the link in my answer. Under "Different aggregations per column."